# type-graphql make exception from Field Resolver

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

I have a following Entity and Resolver for example,

```
    export class SampleA extends BaseEntity {
      @Field()
      @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
      id!: number;
    
      @Field()
      @Column()
      title!: string
    
      @Field()
      @Column()
      answer!: string;
     }


    @Resolver(SampleA)
    export class SampleAResolver {

        @FieldResolver(() => String)
        async answer(@Root() sampleA: SampleA, @Ctx() {req}: MyContext) {
            const msg = "answer is not public";
            if(!req.session.userId) return msg;
            return sampleA.answer;
        }
    }
```

It worked out well. As long as the condition does not meet, the `answer` field will be always "answer is not public" across the entire app. However, if sometimes I want to make a exception out of it，

For example, if I have the following

```
@ObjectType()
class ExceptedResponse {
    @Field(() => String, {nullable: true})
    errors?: string;
    @Field(() => SampleA, {nullable: true})
    result?: SampleA;
}
```

When I try to return the `ExceptedResponse`, the `SampleA` field will always be filtered by the `answer @FieldResolver()` so I cannot get the real `answer`.

So I wonder if I can make it to an exception out of it without manually re-create a whole new field like

```
@ObjectType()
class ExceptedResponse {
    @Field(() => String, {nullable: true})
    errors?: string;
    @Field(() => {id: Number, title: String, answer: String }, {nullable: true})
    result?: {id: number, title: string, answer: string };
}

//then I just manually assign each value inside my graphql method
```

Or ideally if I can make a `SpecialSampleA` extends from `SampleA` without that limitation.

Comment: `@Authorized()` is for that ... returning some error string instead of value? creazy idea ... I wish you: create client with error handling ... feel yourself your API DX

Comment: @xadm No, it's not just about authentication, there are multiple complex condition guards behind, and dedicated for `particular behaviors only`, and at some point it can even `omit authentication`. my minimal condition made it felt like, but `@Authorized()` seems like a way to do it with some modification. By the way, it's not an error. This is just one field go along with many other fields. It should never throw an error. If you look at `@Authorized()` in doc, they did the similar thing. You are too early to judge the whole context without any further info. Anyway Thx for your help.

Comment: Anyway ... general rule: **error message shouldn't be returned in the field** (instead of value, any type, not artificial unions - type+error), it should be null-ed .... additional info can be returned in error/extensions fields ... set yourself in FE dev role, really

Comment: @xadm Again, I do appreciate and agree with you that using null then reflect that message from other fields or frontend. I really felt like you want to say something correct but just put yourself into a weird irony manner. Just simply tell me the problems or facts. It's already far away from the problem itself and unfortunately `@auth` is not for this case.

Comment: just advice (avoid non-standard error handling, typeOrError union fields/etc.), no offense  ... I'm not forcing you to use any specific solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some random tests, it seems like it's extremely simple to achieve my goal.
Just simply create a new class and then assign the `SampleA` result to it. It's auto handled by `type-graphql` and escape the resolve field check because `Class` is changed;

```
@ObjectType()
class ExceptedSampleA {
  @Field()
  inspiration: string;
  @Field()
  answer: string;
}
//inside response
    @Field(() => ExceptedSampleA, {nullable: true})
    result?: ExceptedSampleA;

//inside graphql method like Mutation() then return response
   const sampleA = SampleA.findOne();
   return { result: sampleA, error: someError }
```